# Value of a table column is not what it seems

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2016

I am trying to find all records in a table where the quantity is less than 1.
For this i am using a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Quantity < 1
```

However, i am getting results where the Quantity is actual 1.
The type of this column is FLOAT for some odd reason (Dont ask why, i haven't created it)

How do i know what the exact value is of this column. I tried:

```
SELECT 
  CEILING(quantity) as [Ceiling quantity], 
  FLOOR(quantity) as [Floor quantity], 
  CAST(ROUND(Quantity, 2) AS INT) as [Rounded quantity], 
  Quantity AS [Actual quantity] 
FROM Table
```

But the result is:

```
Ceiling quantity       Floor quantity         Rounded quantity Actual quantity
---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------- ----------------------
1                      0                      1                1
```

I know that technically the quantity *is* lower than one. I am trying to find a decent way of obtaining the actual value this column holds.

Comment: Learn about `floats` -- and then don't use them.  Use `numeric`/`decimal` instead.  The value is not "1".  It is something like `0.99999999999999997`.

Comment: I know the value is not 1, but i want to know what the exact value is. Like i said, i did not create the table, and I can change it ofcourse, but thats not the point here.

Comment: The "exact value" can be inspected as the bits the value is comprised of (`CONVERT(BINARY(8), quantity)`) or else with excessive precision through `FORMAT` (`FORMAT(quantity, 'G17')`), though be careful that the latter uses .NET formatting routines and doesn't necessarily roundtrip when parsed as a T-SQL literal.

Comment: The exact value is 0x3FF0000000000000.

Comment: Close @jarlh it is: 0x3FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Comment: Odd, I did cast float as binary.

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JeroenMostert for providing the correct answer:

```
SELECT 
  FORMAT(quantity, 'G17') as [Format quantity]
FROM Table
```

results in:

```
Format quantity
-------------------
0.99999999999999989
```

Answer (score 0):

The CONVERT method has a style where every distinct float value is guaranteed to convert to a distinct character string. This is style number 3, and it is available in SQL Server 2016 and later. You can read more about the CONVERT method and the different styles here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

You can try it out like this:

```
SELECT Convert (VARCHAR(99), Quantity, 3) FROM Table
```

Comment: This results in 9.9999999999999989e-001

Comment: Yes, this is the scientific notation for 0.99999999999999989. An explanation for that notation is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: In fact, it's accurate to say this is SQL Server's idea of scientific notation. No other systems I've seen format the exponent with three fixed digits. Annoyingly, this is the format SQL Server insists on using when formatting values typed as floating-point in JSON, even if the value is exactly representable as an integer. Probably not a coincidence that both JSON support and this `CONVERT` style first appeared in SQL Server 2016.